# Kafka consumer to read data from topic when from and until offset is known

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, kafka-consumer-api

Can i know if kafka consumer can read specific records when from and until offsets of partitions of a topic are known.

Use case is in my spark streaming application few batch are not processed(inserted to table) in this case i want to read only missed data. I am storing the topics details i.e partitions and offsets.

Can someone let me know if this can be achieved reading from topic when offsets are known.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to process set of messages, that is defined by starting and ending offset in spark streaming you can use following code:

```scala
val kafkaParams = Map[String, Object](
  "bootstrap.servers" -> "localhost:9092",
  "key.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
  "value.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
  "group.id" -> "groupId"
)
val offsetRanges = Array(
  OffsetRange("input", 0, 2, 4) // <-- topic name, partition number, fromOffset, untilOffset
)

val sparkContext: SparkContext = ???
val rdd = KafkaUtils.createRDD(sparkContext, kafkaParams.asJava, offsetRanges, PreferConsistent)
// other proccessing and saving
```

More details regarding integration spark streaming and Kafka can be found: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/streaming-kafka-0-10-integration.html